# Large file upload(like 2gb) in chunk by chunk using javascript ajax and django without any api call

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

```
My views.py file like this
```

Now I have some problem to stich all the chunks into the file in views.py and also take so much time to upload this video file.Please help.

Comment: So ... what is the code and the error you encounter? Pleas be more specific and share enough to make this into a reproducible example. Also ... as a sidenote .... 2 GB file transfers will always take long, regardless of the used platform/code.

Comment: You did not share any `views.py` file...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, this is my fault. I can share another link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69930265/large-video-file-uploadlike-2gb-in-chunk-by-chunk-and-add-those-chunk-to-get-t?noredirect=1#comment123621164_69930265

Comment: Now I want to upload that 2gb video file using chunks and multithreading. IN that link you can give the answer.