# Large video file upload(like 2gb) in chunk by chunk and add those chunk to get the original file using javascript ajax and django without any api call

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

My views.py file like this
Now I have some problem to stich all the chunks into the file in views.py and also take so much time to upload this video file.Please help. This file upload need to ajax form submit, here I am taking the file and slice it into some specific size of chunk and then send that chunk to our video_upload method.

```
def video_upload(request):
  video_upload_response = []
  curr_time = time.localtime()
  curr_clock = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", curr_time)
  if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VideosForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
        if form.is_valid():
              course_id = request.POST.get("course_id")
              print(course_id)
              video_title = request.POST.get("video_title")
              print(video_title)
              video_file_name = request.POST.get("video_file_name") 
              print(video_file_name)
              video_file = request.FILES['video_file']
              # print(list(video_file))
              chunk_data = request.POST.get("chunk_data") 
              print(type(chunk_data))
              print(curr_clock)
              if chunk_data == 'null':
                    print("ok")
              else:
                    chunk_data = bytes(chunk_data, 'ascii')
                    print("hhhhhh")
                    print(type(chunk_data))
                    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))+"/media"
                    file = open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, video_file_name), 'wb+')
                    file.write(chunk_data)
```

return JsonResponse(video_upload_response, safe=False)

```
(function($) {

      var reader = {};
      var file = {};
      var slice_size = 10485760;
      
      $(document).on('click', '.video_form_submit', function(event){
            form_id = $(this).data("form-id")
            // console.log(form_id)
            course_id = $(this).data("course-id") 
            // console.log(course_id)
            video_title = $("#video_title_"+form_id).val()
            file = $("#video_id_"+form_id)[0].files[0]
            csrf_token = $(this).data("csrf-token")
            $("#progress_process_"+form_id).css('display', 'block');
            $("#progress-bar1_"+form_id).css("width", "0%");
            $("#progress-text1_"+form_id).html("0 %");

            start_upload(event, file, csrf_token, course_id, video_title, form_id);
      });


      function start_upload(event, file, csrf_token, course_id, video_title, form_id) {
            event.preventDefault();
            reader = new FileReader();
            file = file
            console.log(file)
            upload_file(0, csrf_token, course_id, video_title, form_id);
      }

      function upload_file(start, csrf_token, course_id, video_title, form_id) {
            var next_slice = start + slice_size + 1;
            var blob = file.slice(start, next_slice);`enter code here`    
            var videoform = new FormData;
            videoform.append("video_file", file)
            videoform.append("course_id", course_id)
            videoform.append("video_title", video_title)
            videoform.append("video_file_name", file.name)
            videoform.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrf_token)
            videoform.append("chunk_data", reader.result)

            reader.onloadend = function(event) {
                  if (event.target.readyState !== FileReader.DONE) {
                        return;
                  }
                  videoform.append("chunk_data", reader.result)
                  $.ajax({
                        url: "/video_upload/",
                        type: 'POST',
                        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                        data: videoform,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                              var size_done = start + slice_size;
                              console.log("size_done")
                              console.log(size_done)
                              console.log("size_done done")
                              var percent_done = Math.floor((size_done / file.size) * 100);
                              console.log(percent_done)
                              if (next_slice < file.size) {
                                    // Update upload progress
                                    // $('#dbi-upload-progress').html(`Uploading File -  ${percent_done}%`);
                                    $("#progress-text1_"+form_id).text(percent_done + '%');
                                    $("#progress-bar1_"+form_id).css('width', percent_done + '%');
                                    // More to upload, call function recursively

                                    // console.log(reader.readAsBinaryString(blob))

                                    upload_file(next_slice, csrf_token, course_id, video_title, form_id);
                              } else {
                                    $("#progress-text1_"+form_id).text(100 + '%');
                                    $("#progress-bar1_"+form_id).css('width', 100 + '%');
                                    // Update upload progress
                                    $('#dbi-upload-progress_'+form_id).html('Upload Complete!');
                              }
                        }
                  });
            };

        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why you are using`+ 1` at the first line of `upload_file`? perhaps you should remove it and use it at success function and using: `upload_file(next_slice + 1, csrf_token, course_id, video_title, form_id)`

Comment: Thank you mrash, it will work. But another thing I want to share that, if I give a 2gb video file to upload, it will take 6/7hours. Is there anything wrong in my code? and how to reduce the time for uploading process. Because it is realy so embarrassing for my client.

Comment: You can use concurrent connections to send parts. for example, split large files into 8 parts and each function send 8x+1th chunk.

Comment: Can you give me some coding example of how to split large files into 8 parts and each function send 8x+1th chunk and also I can not bind each chunk. because of the chunk format is a octa stream base64 format

Comment: Also How to get single chunk data?